# How to enable ECN marking in IP header in Linux

Tags: networking, ubuntu-18.04, linux-kernel, tcpip

Is the ECN marking in the IP header is performed by default in Ubuntu (4.15.x kernel) or should the kernel be recompiled with a special option?
I configured a RED ingress queue at an Ubuntu machine, net.ipv4.tcp_ecn is set to 1 in all hosts of the network and ECN is enabled in the tc qdisc command.

I am using 4 ubuntu machines using this topology: client --- rt1 --- rt2 --- server. 
`iperf -s` is running at the server side and `iperf -c server -P 100 -d` at the client side.
(client --- rt1): 100mbit 1 ms latency; (rt1 --- rt2): 10mbit 1ms latency; (rt2 --- server): 100mbit 1ms latency;

The RED queue is configured at the client-facing interface of rt1 as following:

## Create ingress on external interface

`tc qdisc add dev $ext handle ffff: ingress`

`ifconfig $ext_ingress up`

## Forward all ingress traffic to the IFB device

`tc filter add dev $ext parent ffff: protocol all u32 match u32 0 0 action mirred egress redirect dev $ext_ingress`

## Apply RED on the IFB device

`tc qdisc add dev $ext_ingress root red limit 50000 min 4167 max 12500 burst 7 avpkt 1000 probability 0.5 bandwidth 100mbit ecn`

I see dropped packets as early drop due to congestion but there are no marked packets.

Comment: With the 10mbit between rt1-rt2 (and so between client and server), will there ever be packets that need marking?

Comment: The link between the client and rt1 is 100mbit. I am afraid that the average queue exceeds the maximum threshold most of the times, therefore the RED queue degenerates into a simple Tail Drop queue. I think I might check the RED parameters. It's very confusing though.

Comment: RED is handling rt1 -> client  (root option).   Since packets arriving on rt1 from rt2 destined for the client, come in at max 10mbit, how could they ever exceed their queue?

Comment: Question updated!

Comment: I wonder why, with iperf3, you can specify the congestion control algorithm  ("-C" option).

Comment: I need to use RED queuing discipline in order to compare it with another system/framework that uses TCP Reno Congestion control with combined with RED.

It's weird that ECN marking is done when I use fq_codel. It should definitely be related with some RED parameters.

Comment: ECN is turned on by default with fq_codel.  It wouldn't be that the order of the parameters is important?  tc qdisc ... red limit bytes [ min bytes ] [ max bytes ] avpkt bytes [ burst packets ] [ ecn ] [ harddrop] [ bandwidth rate ] [ probability chance ] [ adaptive ]   Grasping at straws here.

Comment: Perhaps try iperf3?   ECN will only be used with "packets which indicate that their hosts honor ECN".  Can that be verified in the packets you receive?

Comment: Tried the parameter order and iperf3 but still the same. tcp_ecn sys variable is set to 1 everywhere in the network. I can see from the .pcap file that the TCP-ECN-Echo Flag is set during the 3-way-hanshake and the packets have ip.dsfield.ecn set to 10 as ECN-Capable hosts, but the CE bit in the IP header is never set, even though I have overlimits dropped packets from ```tc -s -d qdisc```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107903/discussion-between-kr1stj0n-and-gerard-h-pille).

Answer (score 0):

You should verify your kernel configuration for:

```
IP_NF_TARGET_ECN
NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_ECN
```

Perhaps with the Ubuntu kernel, it's just an extra module that needs to be loaded.

Comment: These options are compiled as modules.
I loaded ```modprobe ipt_ECN``` and ```modprobe xt_ecn``` but didn't change anything.